# Write Pandas Dataframe to MYSQL database with SSH

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, pandas-to-sql

### The Problem

I would like to use the pandas  [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to write a dataframe to a MYSQL table. **However, my connection requires SSH**.

### What I have tried

I have a successful connection to execute queries with pymysql, but being able to directly use a function like to_sql would make my life a lot easier to be able to directly push the data like that. See below for my code that I'm working with.

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import pymysql as db
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

host = 'host'
localhost = 'localhost'
ssh_username = 'ssh_username'
private_key = '/path/'

# database variables
user='user'
password='password'
database='database'

#query function that works for pulling from database
def query(q):
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (host, 22),
        ssh_username=ssh_username,
        ssh_private_key=private_key,
        ssh_private_key_password="password",
        remote_bind_address=(localhost, port)
    ) as server:
        conn = db.connect(host=localhost,
                               port=server.local_bind_port,
                               user=user,
                               passwd=password,
                               db=database)

        return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)

# What you need to for to_sql
 conn = db.connect(host=host,
                        port=port,
                        user=user, 
                        password=password,  
                        db=database)

# test df
np.random.seed(0)
number_of_samples = 10
frame = pd.DataFrame({
'feature1': np.random.random(number_of_samples),
'feature2': np.random.random(number_of_samples),
'class':    np.random.binomial(2, 0.1, size=number_of_samples),
},columns=['feature1','feature2','class'])

# to_sql
frame.to_sql(con=conn, name='test_table', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

### Maybe Something Else?

I'm considering looking into **turning a dataframe into a CSV file and then importing it into the database**. Please let me know if you have any clue how to use something like to_sql with SSH.

Comment: why does your connection require `ssh` to work, should be able to access your db by using the ip of your server

Comment: We use SSH for security reasons. I talked to our main architect yesterday and informed me that we have to connect via SSH in some way. _However_ I'm looking into [local port forwarding](https://serversforhackers.com/c/ssh-tricks) or a work around like this, but I think our admin has this blocked too for now. At the moment I have about developed a solution to convert it to csv. Not what I was looking for, but it will get the job done :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using [local port forwarding](https://serversforhackers.com/c/ssh-tricks)
to solve this problem.

This is what I used **in the terminal** for local port forwarding:

```
ssh -N -v SSH_user@SSH_host -L3306:127.0.0.1:3306
```

I used **sqlalchemy** for the connection:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/db?charset=utf8"
df.to_sql(con=engine, name='test_table', if_exists='replace')
```